# How can I merge 2 access tables, keeping all data from table a and updated data from table b

Tags: sql, ms-access, merge, vba

Table A has a population of names and unique ids. Table B has the same unique ids and names. The majority of the names in table B are null, but some have an updated name. I want to merge the two tables so I get the old names from table A and new names from table B if they exist. Basically layer table B on top of table A to capture changes to the names.

I've done something like this in sas, but am having a problem in Access. merging via sas is no longer an option. can this be done in access?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL using the`IIF`and`ISNULL`functions to select the name from the correct table (from TableA if TableB is null, otherwise from TableB). If your tables has two fields:`(id`,`the_name)`a query could look like this:

```
SELECT a.id, IIF(ISNULL(b.the_name), a.the_name, b.the_name) AS the_name
INTO TableC
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.id
```